# HTML5 Ajax Upload - Degradable?

Tags: ajax, html, upload

I'm looking at this technique of uploading a file using Ajax:

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-file-upload-progress-bar/

I have two questions about it.

1. It seems to work on my computer using IE9. I was under the impression that it requires IE10+ according to caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi
2. What happens to a users computer who doesn't have an up-to-date browser, will it work like a traditional upload field in IE6 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload files with Ajax without Html5 and you don't need the File Api to do that either. The progress event however is a feature of the XMLHTTPRequest v2, so you'll have to handle that differently for older unsupporting browsers or not show progress at all :)

Alternatively you could write your own upload handler that would report how much of the file has been sent, and then just probe it every x seconds to ask how far it has come. I think Telerik does this with their controls for ASP.NET and MVC.

Comment: Apparently I need MLHttpRequest2 object for the upload itself